# TFS2017 Custom build task with pickList - error converting to System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

Tags: json, tfs, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to build my first custom build task and I'd like to use a drop-down parameter type so in the task.json file I added the below input:

```
{
  "defaultValue": "None",
  "helpMarkdown": "tbd",
  "label": "Is Light",
  "name": "islight",
  "options": {
    "yes": "yes",
    "no": "no"
  },
  "required": true,
  "type": "pickList"
}
```

But when I try to publish the extension with `tfx extension publish --service-url $(Server) --token $(PersonalAccessToken)` to the on-premise TFS I get the below error:

> error: Extension validation failed. Please address the following
>   issues and retry publishing. error: The task.json for contribution
>   extension1 could not be deserialized.Error converting value
>   "@{yes=yes; no=no}" to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]'.
>   Path 'inputs[4].options', line 60, position 54.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi ds19, any update on this, you code posted above looks ok, I have also verified my side. Even though `None` is not in the `options` list, it will not cause  such an error. The "yes" will appear in the picklist of default value instead of `none`.  Go through the error info, it seems you are using `;` instead of `,`, have you double checked this in your local code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error there. Your default value is not in the options. Please change it to either yes or no

Comment: I changed the default value to yes and I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error info

> Error converting value "@{yes=yes; no=no}" to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]'.

Double check you are   using the right  syntax  in your **local code** such as:

`"yes": "yes","no": "no"` instead of `"yes": "yes" ; "no": "no"`

---

By the way, if you want the default value be empty, please use the `"defaultValue": ""`, instead of `"defaultValue": "None"`.